# In python,how to output all the files name with the same extension in a directory?

Tags: python

I want to output the files name by using ~/*.java command. I can check if it is a java file but I really don't know how to output and read all the files by *.java command.

Answer (score 6):

Use the [glob](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) module:

```
import glob
glob.glob('*.java')
```